# Unable to click "Sign Up" button for creating the Facebook account

Tags: robotframework

```
*** Test Cases ***
SignUp
open browser    ${url}     ${browser}
maximize browser window
set selenium speed    2s
Click Element    xpath://a[text()="Create New Account"]
input text    name:firstname     sneha
input password    id:password_step_input    Sneham@8989
select from list by label    birthday_day     23
select radio button    sex      1
click button      xpath://a[text()="Sign Up"]
```

I Have tried the above code to Sign Up Facebook account.
Tried with different scenarios like with ID, Name, Xpath and Text; but none of those able to identify the element.
Please help with the above issue

Comment: _"none of those able to identify the element"_ - which element are you talking about?

Comment: 'click button      xpath://a[text()="Sign Up"]'  Not able to identify the mentioned element, Please help with the same @BryanOakley

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual error message.  Also, have you paused the test immediately before that line to verify that this element is actually on the page?

Comment: No I have not paused the test before verifying  the element @BryanOakley

Answer (score 1):

The "Sign Up" is a button.

What about `click button      xpath://button[text()="Sign Up"]` ?